# Set of desiderata or set of desiderate?

Tags: latin

Desideratum is a desired feature.
Which form is right?

Google search shows that "set of desiderata" is more common. But is it correct?

e.g., a sentence

In this paper, a set of desiderate for memory systems of companions will be presented, together with case studies of the memory subsystems of two existing

or

We formulate a set of desirable characteristics, or “desiderata” for a generic IDR.

Comment: Since most people will assume that _Desiderata_ is a reference to the 1927 "poem" by Max Ehrmann, I wonder if that is a wise choice in any form. What is wrong with _desired features_ or even _requested features_ where the form of the plural is well-understood.

Comment: it became a technical term in my academic field. So to trigger the analogy in reader's minds, use of this term is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

That’s wrong.  This sort of singular *-um* forms a plural in *-a*.

Your cited paper paper was misunderstanding it to be, I dunno, maybe Italian not Latin, like more than one *donna* being several *donne*.

That does not apply here.  And neither does having more than one *antenna* give you several *antennae*.

It is just *desideratum* in the singular, *desiderata* in the plural.

But given the *datum/data* controversy, not to mention *bacterium/bacteria* and *criterion/criteria*, all this is treading on mighty thin ice indeed.